# Recent Posts Widget URL / Domain change

Tags: widgets, footer, recent-posts

we use the "Recent Posts Widget" within our page footer.
After we changed the site URL from development to live the links of the "Recent Posts Widget" didn't change.

First we used the plugin "Search & Replace" to change the domain within the database.
Second we changed left over domains by hand within the backend.
But we coulnd't find a where to change the links within the "Recent Posts Widget".
We deleted the widget from the footer and recreated it but that didn't change anything.

Any idea what went wrong or how we can change the domain?

Thanks for your time.

Best regards Klaas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem.
After looking throu the theme/plugin code i noticed that it was altered before and the false links were hardcoded into it.